# Can I add javascript Prototype to my array instance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

So I understand that you can add new methods to your javascript object prototype. 
`myObject.prototype.myFunction = function {}`. I wanted to do the same for my array instance but keep getting errors. Something like this.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]; 

myArray.prototype.bubbleSort = function(){

// sort stuff here. 

}
```

Why is this not allowed ? I thought since arrays inherit from Object you should be able to extend them the same way as objects.

If this is not possible how can I add a . notation function call to my arrays so I can say. `myArray.bubbleSort();` instead of `bubbleSort(myArray);` without adding methods to Array.prototype.

---

**I think my question caused some confusion so please read this section before answering. Thank you.**

My goal is to have an array named `myArray` that has a specific method bubbleSort. I don't want to change the main Array.Prototype.

So later I can do something like this. `var yourArray = new myArray()` so now since `yourArray` is instance of `myArray` it will have access to bubblesort function.

**Can we achieve this without changing the main Array.prototype ?**

Comment: Yes, **Array** `.prototype.bubbleSort`

Comment: Or `myArray.constructor.prototype.bubbleSort = function(){`…`};`.

Comment: If you only want it on a single instance, just add it directly. `myArray.bubbleSort = function() { ... };`. Simple as that. Adding it to the prototype means it will be added to many instances.

Comment: @xofux Thank you. This works but can you please elaborate on why this works ? Does it have side effects ? Will all the other array methods work once i do this ?

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi Based on your update, juvian has the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are also objects, so you can easily add it as a function to only that array:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]; 
myArray.bubbleSort  = function(){console.log(this)}
```

Beware that if you do this in a library, you might break code like this:

```
for(var i in myArray){
    console.log(i)
}
```

Because that will also give the bubbleSort property

A nicer way would be to extend an Array to make a wrapper:

```
function sortableArray(){
    return this
}

sortableArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

sortableArray.prototype.bubbleSort = function(){
  console.log(this)
}

var arr = new sortableArray()
arr.push(1)
arr.push(0)
arr.push(9)
arr.bubbleSort();
```

Comment: The *"nicer way"* doesn't entirely replicate an Array. For example, mutations of the `.length` property won't behave as you'd expect. Adding a function to the object doesn't actually break code using a `for-in`. If they're using that kind of loop, then they should *expect* to get all enumerable properties. If they only wanted indices, they'd use a `for` loop.

Comment: @squint you are right, first method should be preffered unless you have the risk of another library setting array.bubbleSort property

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding what the prototype is for. The prototype provides a chain for objects to link other properties and methods to a given object.

For example, when you create an array

```
[]
```

that array has access to various functions like `forEach`, `reduce`, etc. because they are linked to, or inherited through, the prototype. Modifying that prototype will modify all objects which inherit from the same prototype.

```js
var aNewArray = [6, 7, 8];
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// myArray.constructor.prototype will give you access to myArrays prototype
myArray.constructor.prototype.forMyArrayOnly = function() {
  console.log(this === myArray ? 'this is myArray' : 'this is NOT myArray!');
};

myArray.forMyArrayOnly();
aNewArray.forMyArrayOnly();
```

If you just want to add a method or property to a *single* object, you don't want to modify their prototype chain. Instead, you want to add that property directly to the object.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
myArray.bubbleSort = function() {
  console.log('I totally just did bubble sort. Check it out');
  console.log(this);
};

myArray.bubbleSort();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have used `Array.prototype.bubbleSort`

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]; 

Array.prototype.bubbleSort = function(){

    console.log("Do bubble sort here");

}

myArray.bubbleSort();
```

Comment: Thank you but I already know this. My question is about extending a single instance.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi he means instead of using `myArray.prototype.bubbleSort()` the proper syntax is: `Array.prototype.bubbleSort()`

Comment: :) I understand the proper syntax but I purposefully wrote it that way to make sure it is obvious that I don't want to add to the main Array.prototype. I want to change just a single instance.